# How to change extravote.php for put structure markup

Tags: structure, markup, microdata

I have a Joomla website. Need in extravote.php add Google Structured Data.

This is the source code:

```html
$html="
<div class=\"extravote-container".$stars."\"".( $xid != 'x' ? "" : " style=\"margin-top:5px;\"" ).">
  <ul class=\"extravote-stars".$stars."\">
    <li id=\"rating_".$id."_".$xid."\" class=\"current-rating\" style=\"width:".(int)$percent."%;\"></li>
    <li><a href=\"javascript:void(null)\" onclick=\"javascript:JVXVote(".$id.",1,".$rating_sum.",".$rating_count.",'".$xid."',".$counter.");\" title=\"".JTEXT::_('Very Poor')."\" class=\"ev-one-star\">1</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"javascript:void(null)\" onclick=\"javascript:JVXVote(".$id.",2,".$rating_sum.",".$rating_count.",'".$xid."',".$counter.");\" title=\"".JTEXT::_('Poor')."\" class=\"ev-two-stars\">2</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"javascript:void(null)\" onclick=\"javascript:JVXVote(".$id.",3,".$rating_sum.",".$rating_count.",'".$xid."',".$counter.");\" title=\"".JTEXT::_('Regular')."\" class=\"ev-three-stars\">3</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"javascript:void(null)\" onclick=\"javascript:JVXVote(".$id.",4,".$rating_sum.",".$rating_count.",'".$xid."',".$counter.");\" title=\"".JTEXT::_('Good')."\" class=\"ev-four-stars\">4</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"javascript:void(null)\" onclick=\"javascript:JVXVote(".$id.",5,".$rating_sum.",".$rating_count.",'".$xid."',".$counter.");\" title=\"".JTEXT::_('Very Good')."\" class=\"ev-five-stars\">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><div class=\"extravote-aggregate\">
<div>
  <span id=\"extravote_".$id."_".$xid."\" class=\"extravote-count\"><small>
<div>";
```

These are the changes I want to add:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/Organization\">
<span itemprop=\"name\" content=\"<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>\">
  <span id=\"extravote_".$id."_".$xid."\" class=\"extravote-count\"><small>
<div itemprop=\"aggregateRating\"
    itemscope itemtype=\"https://schema.org/AggregateRating\">";
```

But this stroke does not work:

```html
<span itemprop=\"name\" content=\"<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>\">
```

I want to take the title from the Joomla article for Microdata. Please tell me how to make this piece of code work?

Answer (score 0):

Now i choosed very easy variant:

```html
<div class=\"extravote-aggregate\">
<div itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/Organization\">
<span itemprop=\"name\" content=\"text\">
  <span id=\"extravote_".$id."_".$xid."\" class=\"extravote-count\"><small>
<div itemprop=\"aggregateRating\"
    itemscope itemtype=\"https://schema.org/AggregateRating\">";
```

Google Structured Data validator not displaying errors. But i think its not true variant.